# Get before save values for an object in MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is this a safe procedure to keep like nearly 100 fields in my Model into view bag. For auditing I have to store only modified values into the data base.Please help.

```
// In the View
<input type="hidden" name="originalModel" value="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.OriginalModel));" />

// In the controller's post...
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff(YourModel yourModel, string originalModel)
{
    // yourModel will be the posted data.
    JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    YourModel origModel = JSS.Deserialize<YourModel>(originalModel);
}
```

Edit:

```
{"UserKey":1,"FirstName":"xxxx","LastName":"yyyyy","MiddleInitial":"Ee","EmployeeId":null};
```

originalModel string consists above value.

Comment: If you are returning it with the view then why also stick a copy in the viewbag?

Comment: You are correct...I have removed the viewbag. But now i am getting following error:  Invalid JSON Primitive:.   at my deserialize part of the code.

Comment: What does that string look like?

Comment: {"UserKey":1,"FirstName":"xxxx","LastName":"yyyyy","MiddleInitial":"Ee","EmployeeId":null};

Comment: Is this code safe in what context? Are you worried about losing the data or about unauthorized people viewing it?

Comment: No this is intranet site. Our data entry guys use this site